# How to turn off JSHint error?

Tags: javascript, jshint

I have the following error for my files in tests:
`Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.`
It is generated from Chai libraries asserts. How can I turn it off in my `.jshintrc` file? I run a Gulp task based on it.

Comment: If only there were some kind of [resource one could check...](http://jshint.com/docs/) ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the help but it is not on the page you linked :)

Comment: I linked the *documentation*, not a page. It's in the documentation. As is the answer to the question you asked Kazekage about her(?) answer.

Comment: You weren't able to find http://jshint.com/docs/options/#expr from the link T.J. provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can silence it inside of a `.jshintrc` file.

```
{
  ...
  "expr": true
  ...
}
```

Source: http://jshint.com/docs/options/#expr

Answer (score 3):

You can add the following on top of the line that's generating the error :

```
/*jshint -W030 */
```

Reference : http://jslinterrors.com/expected-an-assignment-or-function-call

Comment: I have many lines like this...it would be a solution for a couple of lines, but I want a solution in .jshintrc file