# How to turn off JSHint error in Webstorm?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I have the following error for my files in tests: 
`Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.` It is generated from Chai libraries asserts. How can I turn it off in Webstorm? It makes the line yellow and shows a warning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to turn off JSHint error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568707/how-to-turn-off-jshint-error)

Comment: You can tell WebStorm to parse your `.jshintrc` (I believe it does so by default) and it will follow all rules set in there.

Comment: No it is for Webstorm...not the error message from .jshintrc but for its built in warning

Comment: Yes, just to clarify the comment from @Blacksonic, WebStorm has built-in warnings that are implemented with JSHint, but are configured differently.  IOW WebStorm can invoke JSHint in two different ways, and only one (off by default) uses `.jshintrc`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue here is that WebStorm generates internal warnings *using* JSHint, but this internal mechanism is entirely *separate* from enabling JSHint under Settings/Languages & Frameworks/JavaScript/Code Quality Tools/JSHint.  (If you enable JSHint there, you'll get even more warnings, it seems like JSHint is basically running twice with different configurations.)

You need to configure the inspections in Settings/Editor/Inspections, then in the list on the right, find JavaScript/JavaScript validity issues.  That worked for me to remove the Chai warnings.  (I am using the WebStorm 11 EAP at the moment.)

Answer (score 17):

Had the same issue when using `chai`, here is what fixed it for me —

1. Open Preferences by tapping on `WebStorm` then `Preferences`
2. Search for, `Expression statement which is not assignment`
3. Disable the inspection (see screenshot), hit Apply & OK

[image: Expression statement which is not assignment]

Comment: Note that you can limit this change to just the "Tests" in your project (so that it remains enabled in your mainline code) by tapping on "In All Scopes" and turning the warning off only in Tests. Thanks https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/41#issuecomment-455479235

Answer (score 4):

**It's for phpstorm**

Disable JSHint and configure its behavior in PhpStorm
In the Settings/Preferences dialog ⌘ , go to Languages and Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | JSHint.

On the JSHint page that opens, Unselect the Enable checkbox.

Refer link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/jshint.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Settings/Languages & Frameworks/JavaScript/Code Quality Tools/JSHint, Relaxing Options/Suppress warnings about the use of expressions as statements

Comment: ```"expr": true``` is in my ```.jshintrc``` i use this file for config, but my statement appears as a warning

Comment: can't recreate - no warnings are displayed for me if "expr": true and 'use config files' option is enabled in Settings/Languages & Frameworks/JavaScript/Code Quality Tools/JSHint